# Does Foursquare API supports search by hash tags?

Tags: android, foursquare, hashtag

Does Foursquare API supports search by hash tags? Or rather I would like to ask that Foursquare provides supports for hash tags in their post. Because I saw lot of news which has mix response, so I am not able to decide whether they provide hash tag support or not. Please reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I dont think so. Per 4sq developer API there is no API to search via hashtags. I think 4sq don't use hashtags (although you can specify when you checkin) but these are not searchable or of no importance to 4sq.

You can search by locations/venues using 4sq API: https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search

Comment: OK,Thanks for the answer. And when we see some post on FB for check in using foursquare, we know that there are some hash tags highlighted sometimes, right ? And I believe those tags get Highlighted because FB is supporting hash tags. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes I think FB recently started hashtags so they are highlighted most possibly due to Facebook and not 4sq.